# React native setState using object

Tags: react-native

I have an object that when logged prints the following:

Object {
  "Air Conditioning": false,
  "Attic": false,
  "Basement": false,
  "Bathrooms": false,
  "Bedrooms / Living Areas": false,
  "Crawl Space": false,
}

I would like to setState using the above. I attempted the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setAreaNamesInState(this.props.areas)
}

setAreaNamesInState(areaNames) {
  let areaNamesList = {}

  for (let area of areaNames) {
    areaNamesList[area] = false
  }

  console.log('areaNamesList', areaNamesList)
  this.setState(areaNamesList)
  console.log('Attic', this.state['Attic'])
}
```

It doesn't seem to be working, as when I log Attic above it returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The answers of other users are correct, you could do the following

```
this.setState({ areas: areaNamesList }, () => {
  console.log('Attic', this.state.areas['Attic'])
})
```

The difference is you are trying to set the whole state object with your newly created object, which is a bad practice, while this answer updates a property called areas inside your state object with the provided data.

The console log will execute synchronously after the state is updated with the property areas, and log `false`

As a side note, maybe using `componentDidMount` is a bad idea if the prop is not provided the first time the component is created and rendered, since it's only executed the first time and never again, the property might be undefined by the time you need it.

Consider switching to other lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing curly braces in your `setState` as `this.state` is an object.

```
this.setState({ areaNamesList })
```

Also worth mentioning that `setState` may not be completed before `console.log('Attic', this.state.areaNamesList['Attic'])`. `setState` can take a callback that will be executed when it is complete as such:

```
this.setState({ Attic: areaNamesList }, () => {
  console.log('Attic', this.state.areaNamesList["Attic"])
})
```

Comment: Thanks @MattyK14. I tried this, however attic is still logged as undefined, even in the callback.

Comment: @MollyHarper Since you want to access the Attic property of the `areaNamesList` state, we needed to add that. Sorry, it's been corrected!

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
this.setState({ areaNamesList }, () => {
  console.log('Attic', this.state.areaNamesList['Attic'])
})
```